# Can i place more than 1 Azure media player on a wordpress page?

Tags: html, wordpress, azure-media-services, azure-media-player

i'm trying to embed Azure Media Player in my Wordpress page, so that i can access the videos i'm hosting on Azure using the Azure Media service. I'm embedding the video using standard HTML tags, however, i'm running in to a couple problems.

1. When i try to embed more than 1 AMP on a page, the first two videos works fine, but the third one will not render. I just see the black screen with video controls, but unresponsive. When i put a page break and render the third video on the next page, it renders fine.
2. The big play button on the center is rendered only for the first video. It's not rendered on the second video.
3. I can't seem to figure out how to turn off autoplay.

Here's the HTML code, i embed (i've removed the source and poster paths).

```
<figure><video id="vid2" controls muted autoplay preload="none" fluid="true" width="100%" height="100%" class="vid2 azuremediaplayer amp-default-skin amp-big-play-centered" poster="" tabindex="0" data-setup="{&quot;nativeControlsForTouch&quot;: false}" logo="false">
    <source src="" type="application/vnd.ms-sstr+xml">
    </video>
</figure>
```

Answer (score 0):

Only 1 instance of Azure Media Player is supported per webpage.  To include multiple instances, you can put each player in an iframe.